# Change TFS service account password

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

We have a TFS administrator account that is used to run all of our TFS services and scheduled tasks.  What would be the best way to go ahead and update this password?   Is there any issue with changing the password in Active Directory and then manually updating the account password in the Windows services that use that account? I thought there was another method to do this through TFS administration UI, but I can't seem to find that documentation.

thanks.